# Telerik Radgrid event handler for insert not working?

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I am trying to add an event handler for the OnInsertCommand event.

In the radgrid tag on the aspx page I have set

```
OnInsertCommand="RadGrid1_OnInsert"
```

In the code behind page I have

```
protected void RadGrid1_OnInsert(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
```

However I am receiving the following error when I try to access the page:

> No overload for 'RadGrid1_OnInsertCommand' matches delegate
>   'Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventHandler'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is ASP.Net Web Form. Event argument should be [GridCommandEventArgs](http://www.telerik.com/help/sitefinity/developer-manual/radgrid.net2-telerik.webcontrols.gridcommandeventargs.html).

```
protected void RadGrid1_InsertCommand(object source, 
   GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

For the good practice, you want to name the event name to be **XXX_InsertCommand**.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Telerik.Web.UI.` from the second argument.

```
protected void RadGrid1_OnInsert(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
```